# 2nd latest object through django shell is there any query?

Tags: django, database, python-2.7, django-models

I want to take the 2nd latest or 2nd last object from a database table through the Django shell.

For example: there is this way to take the latest object from Models

```
ModelName.objects.latest('id')
```

Is there any way to find 2nd latest object *without indexing*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order_by` on the `id` of the objects in `reverse`:

```
# order by lateness in descending oerder
models_desc = ModelName.objects.order_by('-id')

#last two objects
last_two = models_desc[0:1]

# 2nd latest
second_latest = models_desc[1]
```

Comment: that's not a my question. but indexing is better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't want indexing, it would be pretty simple

```
ModelName.objects.order_by('-id')[1]
```

Otherwise you could fetch the last one and subtract one from it's `id` value, to get the previous objects

```
ModelName.objects.get(ModelName.objects.latest('id').id - 1)
```

For both, you will need to wrap it into a try-catch block.

Comment: I would prefer the `order_by` approach as opposed to manually computing `ids`. You can't tell which model objects have been deleted

Comment: I agree. Just added it because the question asked for a "no index" solution. Using the index is definitely the better approach.

Comment: agreed, indexing is better approach,
FetchAirwayBill.objects.get(id = int(FetchAirwayBill.objects.latest('id').id)-1)